# How to use enum with grouping and subgrouping hierarchy/nesting

Tags: java, enums, nested, grouping, hierarchy

I have one `enum` 'class' called `Example` as follows:

```
enum Example {
//enums belonging to group A:
   enumA1,
   enumA2,
   enumA3,
//enums belonging to group B:
   enumB1,
   enumB2,
   enumB3,
//enums belonging to group C:
   enumC1,
   enumC2,
   enumC3;
}
```

It's important for my project they all enums I work with belong to `Example` (since this is an argument in a constructor of a class).

How do I use `enum` hierarchy/nesting in order to achieve the following:

- A method that tests whether an `enum` is of group A, B or C. For example, something like `Example.enumA1.isGroupBelonging(Group.A)` or `isGroupBelonging(Example.enumA1,Group.A)` would be a public method that returns true.
- Be able to do the same thing with sub-groups of group `A`, `B` and `C`. For example, group A might have subgroups `a`, `b` and `c`. I then want a method that does something such as `Example.enumA1.isSubGroupBelonging(SubGroup.a)` which is a `public boolean`.
- A way to do all this without needing to have some elaborate `enum` name that clogs up my code. For example, it would be nice to just be able to refer to `Example.enumA1` throughout my other classes without needing to refer to it using something like `Example.enumA1(Group.A,SubGroup.a)` or `Example.enumA1.Group.A.SubGroup.a`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would use a very simple enum constructor which associates the corresponding group with the enum value:

```
public enum Example {

    ENUM_A1 (Group.A),
    ENUM_A2 (Group.A),
    ENUM_A3 (Group.A),

    ENUM_B1 (Group.B),
    ENUM_B2 (Group.B),
    ENUM_B3 (Group.B),

    ENUM_C1 (Group.C),
    ENUM_C2 (Group.C),
    ENUM_C3 (Group.C);

    private Group group;

    Example(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public boolean isInGroup(Group group) {
        return this.group == group;
    }

    public enum Group {
        A,
        B,
        C;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import static Example.*;
import Example.Group;
...

ENUM_A1.isInGroup(Group.A);  // true
ENUM_A1.isInGroup(Group.B);  // false
```

To do the subgroups you can do a similar kind of structure for Group as for Example, using `Group(SubGroup ... subgroups)` as a constructor and an `EnumSet<SubGroup>` to contain the subgroups.

Comment: Excellent solution! I would also add `getGroup()` method to get the current group.

Comment: beauty! Better than what i was looking for!

Answer (score 36):

You can use [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to group various enums without creating a separate [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class:

```
public enum Example {

    ENUM_A1, ENUM_A2, ENUM_A3,
    ENUM_B1, ENUM_B2, ENUM_B3,
    ENUM_C1, ENUM_C2, ENUM_C3;

    public static EnumSet<Example> groupA = EnumSet.of(ENUM_A1, ENUM_A2, ENUM_A3);
    public static EnumSet<Example> groupB = EnumSet.of(ENUM_B1, ENUM_B2, ENUM_B3);
    public static EnumSet<Example> groupC = EnumSet.of(ENUM_C1, ENUM_C2, ENUM_C3);

}   

public static void main(String[] args){
    if(Example.groupA.contains(Example.ENUM_A1)){
       System.out.println("Group A contains ENUM A1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also seen [here](http://jaxenter.com/enumset-in-java-regularenumset-vs-jumboenumset-106051.html)

Comment: is there guaranteed order in EnumSet? for example I want enums for groupA in following order ENUM_A3, ENUM_A1, ENUM_A2.. Not sure EnumSet would guarantee me order

Comment: EnumSet is not garantee the order, but you can use the 'Collections.sort(new ArrayList(Example.groupA))' to order it!

Comment: @Wendel That wouldn't do anything, as you wouldn't have access to the list.